# How to configure access control for Subversion on Fedora 14

Tags: fedora, svn

I'm setting up a Subversion server at my office to help the dev team manage thier code, and better contain the projects somewhere locally in the building.

I've got the server, got svn installed, I can checkout, commit, create repos and the like. The problem is that I have one user! Not ideal.

I've been reading this, http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/svn-subversion-access-control-with-apache-and-mod-authz-svn/

But it seems that I keep overwriting the access file every time I want to add a new user. I can't really be bothered with hooking it into AD right now, but I would like each person to commit using their own username and such.

Does anyone have any idea's on the best way to configure this? I have to add all our code and would rather not have to edit a file in each repository I create! `mkdir` and `chown` etc are taking enough time already ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep overwriting your password file, remove the -c modifier from the htpasswd command. That modifier creates a new file (and hence overwrites your old one) every time you add a user.

The tutorial you are using seems to line it out correctly, is the overwriting of users your only problem?

Comment: Yep, I figured it out, although I did it a stupid way, using -n and copying and pasting into the file! :rolleyes: